# When to return in function in Python?

Tags: python, function, return

I am creating a program that will accept user input and from that, generate a name and a backstory. What I am having trouble with is printing the indefinite articles "a" or "an," depending on the backstory string's first letter.

```
# Backstory
a = "alchemist searching for a missing item"
b = "berry picker who dabbles in meteorology"
c = "camera assistant fascinated by alien civilization"
# this continues for all letters of the alphabet, with each string beginning with its corresponding variable name.

character = (a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m, n, o, p, q, r, s, t, u, v, w, x, y, z)

def indefinite_article():
    for index in character:
        if index in (a, e, i, o, u):
            return("An ")
        else:
            return("A ")
```

What I would like to happen: if a letter from `character` is a vowel, the string "An " will print. If a letter from `character` is a consonant, the string "A " will print.

However, whether vowel or consonant, `indefinite_article()` prints "An ".

I am using a function because I would like to print the result of `indefinite_article()` into a string later on:

```
for char_index in character:
    if char_index[0] == first_name.lower()[0]:
       print("\n\nCHARACTER PROFILE: " + indefinite_article() + char_index)
```

Note: `first_name` is a variable with an input assigned to it.

Where should I place my return statement(s) so that the correct indefinite article is printed depending on the first letter of the backstory string?

Comment: Your `for` loop only checks the first entry in `character`.

Comment: `a` is a variable which holds a long string. `"a"` is the character “a”. Of course these behave very differently when comparing values.

Comment: Also, you don't show how you call `indefinite_article()`

Comment: @quamrana I was under the impression that `for i in tuple` would iterate through the entire tuple?

Comment: Not if you `return` early.

Comment: Now about the call to `indefinite_article()`. You don't have a clear idea of your expectations of the function.

Comment: I see you have started an edit of your question to show how you call your function. If you finish this edit I will try to get your question reopened.

Comment: Oh no! What happened to the example of calling `indefinite_article()`? Your recent edit deleted that bit!

Comment: @quamrana Thank you! I forgot to put that back in after deleting it.

Comment: I can now see how you want to use your function. If the question reopens, I can post an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see from your update that you want to loop over the `character` tuple and provide the indefinite article for the first word in each backstory.

Your calling code does the loop, so the function only needs to concern itself with one item and just the first letter of the item.

So, your calling code could be modified like this:

```py
for char_index in character:
    first_letter = char_index[0]
    if first_letter == first_name.lower()[0]:
       print("\n\nCHARACTER PROFILE: " + indefinite_article(first_letter) + char_index)
```

and the function should be modified to just test that first letter like this:

```py
def indefinite_article(letter):
    if letter in 'aeiou':
        return 'An '
    else:
        return 'A '
```